# Is this way of adding a horizontal line after the frame title stupid?

Tags: beamer, rules, frame-title

I use the default beamer theme, where the `\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}` has:

```
\strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
```

so I ignore the `\par` using `\ignorepar` command in the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\ignorepar}[3]{#2#1}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \let\oldinsft\insertframetitle%
    \renewcommand{\insertframetitle}{\oldinsft\ignorepar\hrule}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frametitle}{Framesubtitle}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Without `\ignorepar`, there would be an empty line between the horizontal line and the subtitle, if it exists:

[image: without \ignorepar]

Comment: with just posting fragments it is hard to see the intent of this code or test it. What do you mean by "empty paragraph"? tex can't really have an empty paragraph. you surely need the `\par` after the`\strut` (or `\hrule` will force one anyway)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle added screenshots

Comment: it would be much better to add a small test file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done

Comment: Thanks but when I run it `Framesubtitle` does not appear?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle works for me locally and in overleaf.

Comment: the example code doesn't produce the image shown but I assume the blank line is a paragraph that just consists of `\strut` not really from `\par`

Comment: I'm using tl2019, let me try an older one...

Comment: Oh OK the subtitle does appear in tl2016

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the definition of `\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}` has changed?

Comment: @presumably. You can put `\ajfhasljvhcascjal` in that second argument and get no error, it doesn't appear to be used at all.

Comment: thanks to SamCarter for pointing out https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/613bb662d315326b3d93cc6823b0f4ede941b85b

Comment: @DavidCarlisle need to test if the next cmd is `\strut`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92012/discussion-between-latex-rulez-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, the intent of dropping `#3` in `\ignorepar` is to generate

```
\strut\insertframetitle\strut\hrule
```

instead of

```
\strut\insertframetitle\strut\par\hrule
```

However the second form is preferable. `\hrule` is a vertical mode construct so if used after the `\strut` it is essentially an error condition from which TeX will silently recover by automatically inserting `\par` and then re-reading the `\hrule` token.

---

With texlive 2019 the subtitle argument is not processed at all, but using texlive 2016 you can see that the effect is not due to ignoring `\par` you get the same output if you re-insert `\par` (which is `#3`) and define the command as

```
\newcommand{\ignorepar}[3]{#2#3#1}
```

The important point is to do the `\hrule` after the `\strut\par` not before.

Comment: Instead of `\strut\insertframetitle\hrule\strut\par`! The `\ignorepar` command swaps the arguments.

Comment: @LaTeXrulez you make it hard to trace since you provided no usable example. `\hrule\strut` would be bad OK you want the hrule after the `\strut` but as I say putting it after the `\par` would be better

Comment: @LaTeXrulez I adjusted the wording to clarify that I was just discussing the dropping of `\par`

Comment: @LaTeXrulez sorry I rejected your edit, you removed the `\par` from before the `\hrule` leaving the following paragraph saying why the `\par` is better meaningless.

Comment: But your "instead of" is wrong... If I replace `\y` in `\x\y\z` with `\y\w`, I'll get `\x\y\w\z`, not `\x\y\z\w`

Comment: @LaTeXrulez you dropped `#3` to drop `\par` and the point of the answer is to say that you should not do that, you _do_ need to shuffle the tokens round so that `\hrule` comes after the `\strut` (and preferably after the `\par`)

Comment: I've swapped `\hrule` and `\strut`. This is the key point of the `\ignorepar` macro. (At first, there was `#3`, but then I've noticed it works without it.)

Comment: @LaTeXrulez yes exactly, that is the modified definition that is In the answer. The extra space is not due to a "empty paragraph" and removing the `\par` does not remove it, it is a pargraph with (just) a `\strut`  and the important thing is to add the `\hrule` after the `\strut` not before. So the macro should not be called `\ignorepar` as ignoring `\par` is not what is happening here,